# How to load image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Hi I am trying to load an image from a folder for a particular user but I am not able to do so in flutter.

Below are the details :
location of the image is saved in the database :

```
"profile_pic" : "http://localhost:3001/Users/Desktop/images/1662aa6516bb523107eb225022582e7a"
```

Now when placing a get request for the profile information I get the following details :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62df39120bfefe4ce66ae41b"),
    "userId" : 3,
    "name" : "Akash",
    "company_name" : "Facebook",
    "profile_pic" :"http://localhost:3001/Users/Desktop/images/1662aa6516bb523107eb225022582e7a",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2022-07-26T00:44:58.310Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

now I want to show the image whose location is given in the profile_pic but not able to do so.

```
CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade800,
                backgroundImage: const NetworkImage(profile_pic),
                child: const Text('AM'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 70),
```

getting the following error message :

```
Failed to load network image.
Image URL:
http://localhost:3001/Users/Desktop/images/1662aa6516bb523107eb225022582e7a
Server response code: 404
```

app.js

```
router.post('/userprofile/check/upload', upload.single('profile_pic') , async (req,res) => {
    
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
    console.log(url);
    var filepath = url + '/Users/Desktop/images/';
    var reqFiles = (filepath + req.file.filename)
   

    const notify = new userInfo({
        userId: req.body.userId,
        name:req.body.name,
        company_name: req.body.companyName,
        profile_pic: reqFiles  
    })
    
    try {
        
      await notify.save()
      res.status(201).send();
      
      console.log('201');
    } catch(e) {
        //res.status(401);
        return  res.send(e);
    } 
})
```

The above app.js code stores the file in the specified folder
for example : 1662aa6516bb523107eb225022582e7a
but without any file extension,On checking the folder the file exists.

Hence if you could please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Let me know if you require any further information from my end.

Comment: the thing is your local host may be not accessible to your device/mobile in which you are testing. for that connect both device on same network and try to load this url in browser. if it loads there and not in mobile then add ` android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in andorid mainfest's `application` tag.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I am trying to load the image in flutter web view so trying to find a simple way to load the images as I have to show multiple images in list view.Hence if you could please let me know what changes I need to make in the above code for the image to flow

Comment: Your server returns 404, which means the image is not found.

Comment: Hi I have just updated my code showing how the file is saved in node js and also checked and the file exists in the specified folder

Answer (score 0):

try to check your url in browser if it is load image or not

if your image url is valid then it will render your image else it will throw an error, so use `cached_network_image`

your can manage error and placeholder with `cached_network_image`

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "your url",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Comment: Hi I checked loading the image url in the browser but getting the error message Cannot GET /Users/Desktop/images/1662aa6516bb523107eb225022582e7a..does this mean that the method of saving the file in post method is incorrect?

Comment: Hi I am getting the error Failed to detect image file format using the file header.
File header was [0x3c 0x21 0x44 0x4f 0x43 0x54 0x59 0x50 0x45 0x20]. Can you please help me resolve this